# Convergence uniform of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> I need to find  $x$ that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$ is convergence and uniform convergence

for $\require{cancel}\xcancel{x\ge0}$${\color{red} {x \in \mathbb{R}}}$ we get that $\frac{1}{\textbf{x^2}+n}$ in monotone decreasing so its Leibniz and its convergence .

now I need to check if in interval $x$ so that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$ is uniform convergence :

$$|\sum _{k=n}^{\infty }\:\frac{(-1)^k}{x^2+k}|=|r_n(x)|\le a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{x^2+n+1}$$

$$sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}|r_n(x)|=\frac{1}{n+1}:n\to \infty = 0$$

Is this correct ? if not how can I find a different $x$?

thanks

Comment: how do you get the first estimate

Comment: Uniform convergent isn't a local property, which means that you cant converge uniformly for $x=2$ and $x=4$ for example, it is always on a specific domain.

Comment: @Atmos Why not? It converges uniformly on $\{2, 4\}$. Of course this is equivalent to converging for $x = 2$ and  $x = 4$ separately, but still.

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in what you did. First you write: “for $x\ge0$ we get that $\frac 1{x^ 2+n}$ in monotone decreasing”. Why for $x\geqslant0$? What's different if $x<0$?

You can also prove that your series converges uniformly in $\mathbb R$ using Dirichlet's test for uniform convergence.

Comment: He used the bound from the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test):

If $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a strictly decreasing nonnegative sequence converging to $0$ then

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (-1)^ka_k\right| \le a_{n+1}$$

Applied to $a_n = \frac{1}{x^2 + n}$ he got:

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{x^2 + k} - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{x^2 + k}\right| = \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{x^2 + k}\right| \le \frac{1}{x^2 + n + 1} \le \frac1{n+1} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

uniformly in $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is this wrong?

Comment: @mechanodroid You are right. I misread what the OP wrote and it seemed to me that the absolute value sign was placed *inside* the sum. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: my bad I missed that it is $x^2$, anyway thanks a lot